# GetOriginalEntityState throws "The entity is not of the correct type" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When calling `GetOriginalEntityState`, I get the error

> The entity is not of the correct type.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
User user = userTable.ToList().Where(x => x.UserID == UserID).FirstOrDefault();
if (userTable.GetOriginalEntityState(user) == null)
{
}
```

It makes no sense that a User pulled from the userTable would be the wrong entity type.  But there is no explanation about "which" entity was wrong.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in my data model for User, I had forgotten to mark UserID as the identity field.

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
public int UserID { get; set; }
```

And all is well...